# Error in Correlation function in R

Tags: r, correlation

Hi I am trying to use findCorrelation function but getting this error. I cannot understand what this error is all about.

```
Error in findCorrelation(descrCor,cutoff = 0.7) :
only one variable given
```

Code is as follows:-

```
numeric_ds<-modified_ds[sapply(modified_ds,is.numeric)]
numeric_ds[is.na(numeric_ds)]<-0
descrCor <- cor(numeric_ds)
highlyCorrelated <- findCorrelation(descrCor,cutoff = 0.70)
```

How to avoid this kind of error and what this is about.

Comment: Please provide a snippet of the dataset.

Comment: Which package are you using?

Comment: The sample is like this.
"","indicator"
"1",0

am using caret,plyr,and corrplot packages.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for chancing missing values to 0? You can always exclude `NA` with `use="pairwise.complete.obs"` or `use="complete.obs"`in `cor()`.

Comment: Hi Olli  i have used the use="pairwise.complete.obs" but still the error is same.